# How to get children in Acitree

Tags: acitree

I used aciTree to view list items. After sorted i want to list all children of parent same level but i can't get them . They're only HTML node li tag. How to return json node.

```
                    case 'sorted':
                        var pr = api.parent(item);
                        var allChilds =  api.children();
                        var arrChilds = api.children(pr, false, false);  

                        $.each(arrChilds, function(id,child) {
                              console.log(api.itemData(child));   // here error  
                         });   

                        console.log(api.itemData(item)); 

                        break;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try the following code:

```
    var api = $("#Tree").aciTree("api");
    var allChild = api.children(null, true, true);// you can change null to any node , now it get the whole tree

    allChild.each(function (index, item) {
        var $item = $(item);
        var data = api.itemData($item);// itemData return json object for the selected item.
    });
```

Comment: To determine if that node is selected use: `api.isChecked($item)`. See the  [docs](http://acoderinsights.ro/source/aciTree/documentation.html#.isChecked)  The value for 'checked' in the variable named `data` refers to the initial JSON data.

Answer (score 0):

itemData wants an item object, and children returns a list of `<li>` items. Try this;

```
    $.each(arrChilds, function(id,child) {
      var item = api.itemFrom(child);
      console.log(api.itemData(item));   // here error  
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var allChild = api.children (item, true, true);
```

you will get all the childs of item and item is null if you want all childs from root